# Is there a function in Excel which calculates how many logical expressions evaluate to TRUE?

Tags: excel, vba

I was wondering if there is a function that could be used as `=name_of_function(A1>0, A2>0, A3>0, A4>0, A5>0)`, which would return how many of those logical expressions evaluated to `TRUE`.

Assuming A1>0 and A4>0 but A2, A3 and A5 aren't it would display 2. And if A1, A2, A5 are >0 and A3, A4 aren't it would say 3.

I'd need a function like this, so is there one?

Answer (score 3):

You could use Excel's `+` operator:

```
=(A1>0)+(A2>0)+(A3>0)+(A4>0)+(A5>0)
```

Or you could use the `SUM` function:

```
=SUM(A1>0,A2>0,A3>0,A4>0,A5>0)
```

Comment: the + operator, whatever it is, works for this case, thanks :)

Comment: @Liverpool The `+` operator is used to add two numbers together, e.g. `=4+7` will give a result of `11`.  Or, in your examples, `=1+0+0+1+0` gives `2` and `=1+1+0+0+1` gives `3`.

Comment: sum does not count TRUE as 1... as far as I know

Comment: @DirkReichel A `=SUM(TRUE,TRUE)` doesn't work, but I assume that Excel is using `1` for the truth value when first evaluating the logical expression so, as long as you do the sum before it changes the `1` to `TRUE` it does work.  (At least, it worked in Excel 2016 which I was using to test it.)  And, being so used to VBA where it usually uses `-1` for `True`, I was very surprised that I didn't need to stick a negative sign in the front of the calculations.  (I wish Excel and VBA acted consistently!)

Comment: have done a quick check and the newest excel does count it. At least `SUM(TRUE,TRUE)` is 2

Comment: @DirkReichel OK, I stand corrected, I made the comment that `=SUM(TRUE,TRUE)` wouldn't work after actually testing `=SUM(G9:G11)` (where G9 and G10 contained `TRUE` and G11 contained `FALSE`) and it gave `0`.  So it must be that the `TRUE` in the cell is treated differently to the **constant** `TRUE` (and the result from a logical expression) within the function.  It must be casting those values to numbers, but ignoring non-numeric cells.  (I guess it makes sense. `SUM` is meant to work on numeric cells within the range and ignore non-numeric ones, so it is treating logical as non-numeric.)

Comment: Very useful: `Debug.Print False + 0   ' -> 0` and `Debug.Print True + 0    ' -> -1`

Comment: @paulbica Yes, VBA treats `True` as `-1` while Excel treats `TRUE` as `+1` - which can get **very** confusing.  (But both of them treat any non-zero number as `True`/`TRUE`, so at least they are consistent in that regard.)

Comment: I know what you mean, and I need to remember that distinction (+1 and -1)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A5,">0")
```

***EDIT:*** For non contiguous range you can use

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(INDIRECT({"B4","D4","F4","H4","J4"}),">0"))
```

***NOTE:*** `INDIRECT` is a volatile function

Another alternate formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(LARGE((B4,D4,F4,H4,J4),{1,2,3,4,5})>0))
```

Comment: I hadn't thought of those being the actual tests the OP was wanting to do, but +1 for an answer if they are the real comparisons!

Comment: well, its for B4, D4, F4, H4 and J4, the A1:A5s was as an example and this function is for range, so doesn't work

edit: the one under this works